# Can an EULA (end user license agreement) affect saving a file in different formats?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, pdf

After creating a design for coffee growlers, I attempted to generate PDF files of my work as well as EPS.  For some reason most of my expanded text in my design is missing. Here are images of my work:

[image]
[full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxkpf.jpg)

[image]
[full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XIiP.jpg)

[image]
[full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rScQM.jpg)

The fonts that I used for my designs were from [dafont](http://dafont.com) and were free, but **would the end user license agreements restrict me from saving my work in different formats** and only for use on my PC?  Or is there something else going on that I don't know about?

I have had to manually set my PDF file to open with Adobe Illustrator, just so the PDF would display properly on my PC.

Comment: You can add pictures on imgur(dot)com - then put the links in your question.

Comment: Take Billy's advice and add some images.  Once the links are in the question, one of us can edit it so the images are actually embedded.  Without images, we have no idea what is going on

Comment: Thank you and I will do that.  I will rephrase this question, too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Font licenses vary. It's difficult to state definitively what may or may not be "ok" without actually reading the license.**

In *most cases* the license refers to the font *software*, as in the actual font files, not the work created with the font. License are *generally* there to prevent the sharing and distribution of the actual font software (files).

One *possible* exception in some licenses is usage. Some licenses may restrict "commercial use" of the font. Again, the *only* way to know is to *read the license*. If the license states the font is for non-commercial use, then you would not be permitted to use the font in anything seen as "commercial" - such as designs you then sell or otherwise get paid for.

Final design formats, don't matter really. Whether or not you use the font in a  PDF, AI, PS, INDD file is irrelevant, it's the nature of the work which *may* matter.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you export work in a PDF, with the fonts embedded or turned to outlines, you are allowed to do that with most fonts.  I've never come across any that don't allow that.

What generally isn't allowed, is sending the font files to someone else. That's considered redistribution, which is technically illegal in most instances.

Also, you'll need to check the font licences for free fonts, and find out if they can be used commercially. Some can't be.

As @PickleRick says - there is a difference between sending work you've done using fonts, in comparison to sharing the actual fonts files.  If we couldn't share work we've done using a font - then what would be the point of having fonts?